# How can I link to a specific point in a YouTube video from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, youtube

When using YouTube on the desktop, right clicking a video gives the option to copy a link to a specific point in that video.

Is there a way to link to a specific point of a YouTube video from an iPhone or iPad?

I've tried using the native iOS app and the mobile site, but I can't find a way to link a specific time stamp.

Comment: Send feedback in the app requesting the feature (and that goes for both you and anyone else who sees this that wants this too)!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The format of the query string is very simple. Just append `?t=#m##s` to the video URL to link directly `#` minutes and `##` seconds into the video. If the URL already contains a `?`, make that `&t=#m##s` instead.

For instance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVPRkcczXCY&t=1m22s will take you 1 minute and 22 seconds into the presentation video for the 2016 MacBook Pro.

So just figure out what point in time you want to link to in a YouTube video, and you can make the link yourself.

Comment: This also works with https:// youtu.be links, which is particularly important when creating from iOS. Why the ? param isn’t auto added is anyone’s guess.